# How to change the compute template dynamically

Tags: cloudify

can i modify dynamically

> compute {
>           template "SMALL_LINUX"
>       }

of the recipe for example in the compute section of the service.groovy?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Depends how you define 'dynamically'.

Once you install a service in Cloudify 2.7, you can't change its template. You have to uninstall the service and install it again with a different template.

If you prefer not to modify the groovy service file, you can set the template name to be defined in a property (which should be provided in the .properties file). See more information about recipe parametrization here: http://getcloudify.org/guide/2.7/developing/recipe_parameters.html

The important thing to remember about properties files is that you can override the property value defined in the properties file by passing an .overrides file in the install-service/application command. See more information here: http://getcloudify.org/guide/2.7/deploying/deploying_srvs.html :

> During the installation you can use an external properties file to
>   override properties in the service recipe. To do so use the
>   install-service commands with the -overrides flag, pointing to an
>   external properties file. The file may contain groovy statements in
>   the same manner as the internal recipe properties file.